# How to compare nullable fields no JPA

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'm using JPA (EclipseLink) on my project.

I have a object called `CelulaArmazem` that have a `produto` and a `cliente` that can be null or not.

The following jpql is an exemple of what I trying to do. I want get the `CelulaArmazem` that have `max(dataInclusao)` for a pair of `produto` and `cliente`.

This query returns data only when `cliente` is not null, but I want the data when `cliente` is null two.

```
select c from CelulaArmazem c
where
c.armazem.id = :idArmazem
c.dataInclusao = (
    select distinct max(c2.dataInclusao) from CelulaArmazem c2
    where
        c2.armazem.id = c.armazem.id and
        c2.produto.id = c.produto.id and
        ((c.cliente is null and c2.cliente is null) or 
        (c.cliente.id = c2.cliente.id)) )
```

It seams to fail when it try to access `cliente.id` of a null object.

How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: Do you get any exception? I would suggest you create a left outer join instead of c.client is null

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Simon, your idea solve the problem:

```
select c from CelulaArmazem c
left join c.Cliente cl
where
c.armazem.id = :idArmazem
c.dataInclusao = (
    select distinct max(c2.dataInclusao) from CelulaArmazem c2
    left join c2.Cliente cl2
    where
        c2.armazem.id = c.armazem.id and
        c2.produto.id = c.produto.id and
        ( (cl is null and cl2 is null) or 
        ( (cl is not null and cl2 is not null) and (cl.id = cl2.id) ) )
```